# Should dynamic asp.net controls be avoided

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, controls

Should dynamic asp.net controls be avoided at all costs?

In what situations should they be used?

What do you use as their replacement?

Answer (score 2):

1. No
2. When you don't know until runtime the control you want to instantiate
3. I am not afraid of dynamic controls..

For rehydrating them on post back I use a [DynamicControlsPlaceholder](http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx)

It's great when you want to bring a control back with it's viewstate without having to reconstruct it yourself on each request.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly avoid them if a postback is required. Reconstructing them is a pain. When possible build them inside a `<asp:repeater>` or other control which can be databound.

Answer (score -1):

1) Unnecessary complexity always should be avoided.
2) When they are necessary.
3) Lesser complicated options.

Comment: Could you expand on all three.  Thanks.